# The bootstrap modal does not show on the first time after calling php file by using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display a modal by using `bootstrap` framework. Before showing modal, I let my web application connect to `php` file to get some data. Once data is being delivered by the `php`, it supposes to display the modal but it does not work. But when I clicked on the second the modal is shown normally.

Why the modal is not showing on the first time I click? But it does show the second time I click.

This is how I called `php` file

```
function btnClick(id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'helpers/helper_functions.php',
    data: {action: 'test'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output) {
        if (output['data'] != null) {
            const session = output['data'];
            $('$entryModal').modal('show');
            showModal(id, session)
        } else {
            if (output['error'] != null) {
                console.log(output['error'])
            } else {
                console.log(output)
            }
        }
    },
  });
}
```

This is `showModal` function

```
function showModal(entry_id, session) {
$('body').on('show.bs.modal', '#entryModal', function () {
    $('#video_wrap').html(
        '<div id="some_id" style="width:640px;height:420px;">session</div>'
    );
    // 
})
$('#entryModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('the modal is shown')
});
$('#entryModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    //
});
}
```

This is the html file

```
<button id="watch_btn" type="button" class="smallBtn" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#entryModal"  onclick="btnClick('<{ $data }>')">
                                    <{ $data }>
                                </button>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="entryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                     aria-labelledby="entryModalDialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="max-width: fit-content;"
                                         role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 640px;" >
                                            <div id="video_wrap"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be related to PHP. to make your question complete, include return value of your PHP code which you get from Ajax call

Comment: @AaA I just got it works. I didn't return the php value correctly